# Training an SVM, my testing set is smaller than training set, is this okay?

Tags: svm, dataset, sample-size

So I have some data as follows:

Total features: 90

Training Data samples: 9000
Testing Data samples: 2500

Do these numbers look okay? I hope my testing data is not to small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610074/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-how-to-divide-a-dataset-into-training-and-validatio

An 80-20 proportion is a good start, which is the case for your data. If you have the ability to do multiple trainings/testings by randomly shifting around the 80/20 proportion, you will get a better insight into the robustness of your trained model and the expected accuracy.

Comment: Already doing k fold cross validation on the training data. Testing directly on the test data afterwards.